# For en-US, toLocaleDateString is converting “00:30” to 24:30

Tags: angular, typescript, time, pipe

Why the time 00:30 is converted to 24:30 in en-US locale

```
options = {
        year: "numeric",
        day: "numeric",
        month: "numeric",
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: false
      }
    
    let actualDate = value;
    if (typeof value == "string") { actualDate = new Date(value); }
     //this also return me 24:30 for 00:30
    var time = actualDate.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false}); 
    //this also return me Date and time where 24:30 is converted in 00:30
    actualDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
```

But When I pass 'en-GB' (English United kingdom) in above locales methods , it return me the 00:30 for 00:30

```
    var time = actualDate.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false}); 
 
    actualDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
```

Now I really confused here. Because from what i know about 24 hour format is that there is no such thing called 24:30 (00:00 - 23:59) . But by changing the locale which depends upon the user preferences(can be any locale) the value is changed. My question is - ** Is there any time like 24:30 (24 hour format of 12:30 midnight) according to English in United States **

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [hourCycle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/hourCycle).

> The Intl.Locale.prototype.hourCycle property is an accessor property that returns the time keeping format convention used by the locale.
>
> **h23 Hour system using 0–23**; corresponds to 'H' in patterns. The 24
> hour clock, with midnight starting at 0:00.

```
var time = actualDate.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hourCycle: "h23"});
```

However, my overall impression is, that en-US locale has AM/PM as default format (hour12, or hourCycle: "h12"), so you will be basically overwriting the default.

Comment: Yes, It does resolved my issue for all the locales probably. I have tested only few locales though. Thank you so much.